# Path between two nodes in graph

Tags: c#, graph, nodes

From an adjacency matrix I have to get the vertex of a path between two nodes doesn't care the weight

[image]

Not sure how to do it well.

```
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="end"></param>
    /// <returns>Returns the path in vertice</returns>
    /// <Complexity>O(n)</Complexity>

    public string[] GetPath(string start, string end)
    {
        int startPosition = 0; //start position 
        int endPosition = 0;  //end position

        for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; i++)
        {                
            if(Vertices[i] == start)
            {
                startPosition = i;
            }
            if (Vertices[i] == end)
            {
                endPosition = i;
            }
        }

        string[] path = new string[0];

        for (int j = 0; j < Vertices.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j >= startPosition && j <= endPosition) {
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

and shortest path

```
public string[] GetShortestPath(string start, string end)
{
 //In this one must return the vertex of shortest path between the nodes but checking the weight
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: if you do not have any hit about the direction the only thing left to do is to check all directions